# Pull the whole layout down on swipeRefreshLayoutListener android

Tags: android, android-scrollview, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout

[image: something similar to image that on call of SwipeRefreshLayoutListener my whole layout should go down]I want to move the whole layout down when SwipeRefreshLayout Listener is called? Is this thing possile in android .? 
This is my whole xml layout.SwipeRefreshLayout contains a progressbar and FrameLayout and that is included in a RelativeLayout.So I want the FrameLyout should pull down when I call for refresh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/horizontal_sync_progress"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/gradient_bg_end"
                        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_drawable"
                        android:visibility="gone"/>

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@+id/container_frag"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what you try till now? Please post some code

Comment: you have to set SwipeRefreshLayout on top in xml file.

Comment: ya..I'll share my xml

Comment: set SwipeRefreshLayout   android:layout_height="wrap_content" it solve my problem

Comment: please post full code of xml

Comment: I posted my full code. did you get what my concern is about ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                    android:id="@+id/swp1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<-----Your design here------>

 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

try this. you have to set your SwipeRefreshLayout above. Hope it helps you. If this doesn't helps you ask me what is the problem i will help you

And My class code is below

```
    mSwipeRefreshLayout1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swp1);
            //set colors if you need 
mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorPrimaryDark, R.color.colorPrimaryLight);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(true);
                    try {

                        //Refresh data

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(e.getMessage()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //customtoast.ShowToast(getActivity(), String.valueOf(e.getMessage()), R.layout.red_toast);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: @Divya this helps you? IF this helps you make this as a correct answer so others getting help from this

Comment: Slow down... You just posted this answer.

Comment: @Zaki it doesn't pull the layout down on call of swipeRefreshLayoutListener . I want to pull the framelayout down. how to do that?

Comment: I'll add an image that may help ti understand my query.

Comment: @Divya please provide full xml code. I think you post half code

Comment: hey @Divya you get the Drawer working with above xml? your Drawer/Navigation is working correctly?

Comment: will catch you after lunch. Sorry

Comment: yes..its working perfectly fine. Even swipeRefreshLayout is working fine but only thing i want to is to pull the whole layout down when I call it

Comment: @Divya Sorry for answering late. But my above code is working in my 4-5 apps correctly. thats why I am damn sure this works

Comment: wait i am searching on it.

Comment: hello @Divya is it ok to use library for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23344581/7320259 this helps you. But if it is ok for u to use library i have better ways to do this

Comment: I think android doesn't support by default, in ios it is possible. bdw Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: you can use library for this if possible

Comment: Ya I can. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can code like this

```
   swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new class(getActivity(), listView, progressBar, mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id, ""), "all", swipe).execute();
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Include code below in your xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    //your xml codes
   </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```