# RecyclerView callback when pulling top

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I've implement an `OnScrollListener` that hide some other `Views` when  my `recyclerView` is scrolled down.
Now I just want a way to show again these `Views` when the user reach the top of the `RecyclerView` and pull it.

**I do not want to use the `SwipeRefreshLayout`**, I don't have anything to refresh and I don't want the bounce effect.
I just need a callback when the user pull at the top set my views visibility to `View.VISIBLE`. **Also I need it to work even if my recyclerView does not contain enough data to fill the screen**.

Didn't find anything on the web that allowed me to do that whitout implementing x useless function, or worked whitout a full recyclerView

Comment: Use SwipeRefreshLayout and then use this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341735/swiperefreshlayout-swipe-down-to-refresh-but-not-move-the-view-pull-down.  You'll get the callback without the pull down animation

Comment: I've just leave work, I'll try that tomorrow and keep it updated, thanks